# Enabling SLAT & correct Can't Start Windows Phone Emulator error

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v

When I run Windows Phone 8 emulator first time this error is shown

> Can't Start Windows Phone Emulator

[image]

My system is a Lenovo, with an Intel Core i5-3470s running on Win 8 Enterprise. [SLAT Status check](http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/) shows following:

> You have a SLAT capable machine, but hardware virtualization is disabled at BIOS level, so please enable it.

[CoreInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) shows:

- AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon HD Graphics
- AMD64 Family 21 Model 16 Stepping 1, Authentic AMD HYPERVISOR
- - Hypervisor is present SVM
- * Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization NP
- * Supports AMD nested page tables (SLAT)
- (- indicates not present, * indicates present)

How do I enable hardware virtualization? I find nothing in the bios to enable SLAT.

**BIOS Images**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Photos of ADVANCE setting**[image]

**Image of Security Tab** 
[image]

**Image of Startup Tab**
[image]

**Image of Device Tab**
[image]

Comment: can any one know the solution?

Comment: This link may be usefull for you.
Check out **Sample instructions for your PC** http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/configure-bios.aspx Please provide BIOS version or images of advanced options menu of BIOS if link above doesn`t helps.

Comment: Waiting for replay.....

Comment: You say you have Intel Core i5-3470s, yet Core info says otherwise. So which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx)

> #### To enable BIOS settings required by Hyper-V
>
> - Restart your computer and press the key required to enter the BIOS settings.
>
>   You can view and change your computer’s BIOS settings
>     by pressing a specific key during computer startup. The key to press
>     varies depending on the manufacturer. It is typically a special key
>     such as <kbd>Del</kbd> or a function key such as <kbd>F2</kbd> or
>     <kbd>F10</kbd>.
>
>   - **Enable** the following items if they are available
>
>   [image]
>
>   - **Disable** the following items if they are available:
>
>     - Intel VT-d
>     - Trusted Execution
>   - Save the settings and restart the computer again.
>   - Next, enable Hyper-V in Windows.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but when i am enter in BIOS at that time there is no option for harsware-assisted virtualization for intel so how can i enable it?

Comment: I think the now it only 2 way to find the solution.

1. Contact LENOVO support http://download.lenovo.com/express/supportphonelist.html
and ask them where you can find needed option.
2. Take fotos of BIOS settings pages. So we can find what options you need to enable.

Comment: :i will select second way

Comment: @ Александр Киричек :please see my edited anser and give solution

Comment: Can you provide fotos for "Advanced" tab?

Comment: @ Александр Киричек:ya sure. i will give you photos of Advance,security,startup and device..

Comment: @ Александр Киричек:I have successfully uploaded all images..Please check it my Edted Question and if possible than give me solution

Comment: Check out "CPU Setup" at the Advanced page.
http://forums.lenovo.com/lnv/attachments/lnv/Tower_Server/517/1/BIOS_VT.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24498/discussion-between-user1774180-and--)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to flash the BIOS to the latest version - http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS029433

but I remember that a clleague of mien could never get it work on the same model. He ended up following my tutorial for using the emulator within VMWare:

```
Install VMWare Workstation v9 on your host OS
Install Windows 8 64-bit as a guest OS
Enable virtualization in Hardware → Processors and select these settings:
    preferred mode: Intel VT-x/EPT
    virtualized Intel Vt-X - selected
```

[image]

The rest is unchecked.

This will allow you to run the Windows 8 SDK/emulator in the VMWare instance without having to deal with the BIOS settings